# Google App Invite Icons

Tags: android, google-play-services, google-play-games, google-app-invites

I planned to integrate the google App invite in my android app. I am concerned on the branding guidelines for the icon that can be used for App invite. Could you please suggest the link where it has the details.

Answer (score 0):

See if this helps you [Asset Studio](https://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/index.html), I couldn't see anything regarding setting icons specifically for an app invite [here](https://developers.google.com/app-invites/android/guides/app)
Will update my answer as and when I learn more.
Cheers

Comment: Thanks. I hope we use the one which is near the heading in the below link https://developers.google.com/app-invites/ios/reference/api/index